# Twython basic, helpm please , can it get easier than this?

Tags: get, twython

This script is giving ma a 500 Error, any ideas?

I am taking the script from a page from python samples and also using the path given to me by my hosting company (and I know it works because I have another script that does work.)

The file has 755 permissions as well as it's directory:

```
#!/home3/master/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/home3/master/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython()
trends = twitter.getCurrentTrends()

print trends
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this code.  The first is you have not included any OAuth data, so the Twitter API will reject whatever you send.  The second is there is no getCurrentTrends() attribute in Twython.  Did you mean get_available_trends or get_closest_trends?